# Method call to display the name of each button clicked in c#

Tags: c#

I want to display the text of each button i click by calling a method.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        disply();
    }
    private int disply()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(??????);
        return 0;
    }
```

I am totally a newbie at c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by passing the text of the Button(Content) if you wana to show the content or by pasing the name if you wana the Name :

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    displayName(button.Name);
    displayText(button.Text);
}
private int displayName(string name)
{
    MessageBox.Show(name);
    return 0;
}
private int displayText(string text)
{
    MessageBox.Show(text);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that `disply` method, you can do it in your `Click` event:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;

    if(button != null)
         MessageBox.Show(button.Text);
}
```

Comment: That's some good advice. Thanks!!. Well I'm a student and I get too many problem with this. Kinda new to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `display` doesn't have any clue about the `Button`. You need to pass that as parameter.

```
private int disply(Button button)
{
    MessageBox.Show(button.Text);
    return 0;
}
```

and then call it like:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    disply(button);
}
```